# Temporary .DS_store files, phantom connections?

Tags: finder, folders, macos

I have my machine set up *not* to write .DS_store files, the reason being because I was suspect they may have been causing access issues on shared drives (folder is considered "in use" even when it isn't), but when I go into a folder, I can still change the view options, which appear to be saved–even with no .DS_file being created–until I unmount the drive.

I'm almost certain now that the issue I'm having is *not* with the .DS_files, but with whatever process is saving and storing the view options locally. This process or whatever it is, is keeping the folder "open", preventing everyone else from editing the folder name or moving it, which is a big deal when you're creating a lot of assets, new folders and moving stuff around while doing housekeeping.

To elaborate, the issue we're having is when a folder is opened in finder, immediately something happens on that machine that is persistent until the drive is unmounted, even when you navigate away from that folder, some kind of lingering connection still exists that registers that folder as "open", even when there is literally *no one* currently viewing the folder contents. I don't know what it is, and this is my question, what is happening when you view the contents of the folder that could cause the server to perceive that folder as still being open or being used by a computer on the network?

Comment: I'm using OSX 10.10.4 by the way.

Comment: how did you set it up not to write .DS_stores on network volumes?

Comment: @Thibmaekelbergh I set up my computer not to write .DS_stores on *anything* using this command: `defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true` I've got finder set up so I can view hidden files as well, so I can confirm that no hidden files are in the folder, or being created, but it seems like something else is still saving the view options in another place other than in a .DS_store file, temporarily at least.

Comment: then it seems you have set it up the right way. Unfortunately I dont have any clue on how to fix your issue, sorry

Comment: @Thibmaekelbergh Ya the issue apparently isn't with the .DS_store files themselves, but perhaps by whatever process writes them? It's as though the .DS_store file info is being prepared, and staged (cached?), but just not written.

Comment: OS X writes a whole lot more than DS files to network volumes, especially if they're NTFS. Investigate Blue Harvest [on phone right now so no link]